# Login error " There has been a critical error on this website"

Tags: login, errors

There has been a critical error on this website and I couldn't find the solution to this.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: You're occurring a fatal error. Enable the debug mode and you should find where it comes from. https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
Or past / send the debug.log, we'll help you P.S: WordPress is WordPress not Word Press ;-)

Comment: Make sure the folder you're using for WordPress has permissions set so that the web server can write to it.